# how to extract text from pdf and dumping the information into a database using python

Tags: database, python-2.7, pdf

how to extract text from pdf and dumping the information into a database using python?
How do I install [PyPDF2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x63yq.png)?

i tried doing it but it shows the following problem

Comment: Please add sufficient details for others to understand the question. Also, please mention the exception and issue you're facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are in Windows, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106380/how-do-i-install-pypdf2-module-using-windows) is how you install it in Windows! You first need to install properly the *setup.py* files.

- cd C:\Users\User\Downloads\pyPDF2 to go into the directory where the setup.py
- C:\python27\python.exe setup.py install I use Python2.7 here. Use C:\python33\python.exe setup.py install for python 3.3 and so on.

That's the fastest way to do it (check the source!!)

On regards of how to extract it, there are lots of tutorials. You should follow the official doc and trustworthy websites! [Here](https://dzone.com/articles/an-intro-to-pypdf2) is an example!

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
def text_extractor(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
        # get the first page
        page = pdf.getPage(1)
        print(page)
        print('Page type: {}'.format(str(type(page))))
        text = page.extractText()
        print(text)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'reportlab-sample.pdf'
    text_extractor(path)
```

Comment: how do i install pypdf2?

Comment: I am not sure you read my answer. At least not the first half. There, I give you a resource and tell you how to do it! @AyushiGarg

Comment: Reading https://pypi.org/simple/PyPDF2/
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/PyPDF2/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'PyPDF2' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for PyPDF2
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('PyPDF2')--not happening

Comment: Did you try the other way of installing it (showed in the link I provided you)? @AyushiGarg