# I have an error installing Odoo 15 on DigitalOcean Servers

Tags: odoo, digital-ocean, odoo-15, droplet

I'm trying to install Odoo 15 on DigitalOcean Servers
When I try to install the requirements.txt, those errors appears:

1. ERROR: Failed building wheel for greenlet
2. ERROR: Failed building wheel for reportlab
3. ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
4. ERROR: Could not build wheels for gevent, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
5. The systemctl status:
   odoo.service - Odoo 15.0 Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/odoo.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-10-06 04:49:21 UTC; 7s ago
   Duration: 35ms
   Process: 36410 ExecStart=/opt/odoo/odoo-server/venv/bin/python3 /opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo-server.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 36410 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CPU: 30ms

Oct 06 04:49:21 SUCCESS-GATES systemd[1]: Started odoo.service - Odoo 15.0 Service.
Oct 06 04:49:21 SUCCESS-GATES odoo[36410]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 06 04:49:21 SUCCESS-GATES odoo[36410]:   File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo-bin", line 5, in 
Oct 06 04:49:21 SUCCESS-GATES odoo[36410]:     import odoo
Oct 06 04:49:21 SUCCESS-GATES odoo[36410]:   File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/**init**.py", line 75, in 
Oct 06 04:49:21 SUCCESS-GATES odoo[36410]:     import PyPDF2
Oct 06 04:49:21 SUCCESS-GATES odoo[36410]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
Oct 06 04:49:21 SUCCESS-GATES systemd[1]: odoo.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 06 04:49:21 SUCCESS-GATES systemd[1]: odoo.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Please help

Comment: You may have to install PyPDF2 according to the error log. [Here is how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106380/how-do-i-install-pypdf2-module-using-windows)

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to install requirements.txt again after the PyPDF2?

Comment: Yes, it is because the installation was not complete.

Comment: Thanks again. It did not work. The problem is in pyproject.toml. it couldn't read greenlet, lxml or reportlab. Should I downgrade python?

Comment: This is the error: ERROR: Could not build wheels for gevent, greenlet, lxml, reportlab, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: I resolved the issue. The problem was with ubuntu 23. I recreated the droplet and installed ubuntu 22.04. That resolved the entire issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. The problem was with ubuntu 23. I recreated the droplet and installed ubuntu 22.04. That resolved the entire issue. –